# How can I enable rewteet and reply in TWTRTweetView?

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric

The default TWTRTweetView has the ability to favorite and reshare a tweet, but I want to add functionality to retweet and reply to the tweet as well. I know that you can make these calls with STTwitter or using their REST API, but I want to know if it would be possible to add actions to the TWTRTweetView.

Should I just subclass the view and add these action buttons in myself?

Comment: You should try whatever solutions occur to you first, then say what you've tried (people are more likely to answer, not vote you down and not flag the question if you show evidence of effort in your question).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try the subclass method you said and tell us your results. I think that should work tho